# How to control html template output according to the content?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML structure for my website like:

```
....
<div class="column1">dynamic_content</div>
<div class="column2">dynamic_content</div>
<div class="column3">dynamic_content</div>
...
```

Now, I want to have this structure but I want to control the structure according with the contents of each column. For example:

a. If the 'column1' is empty I have two options:

1. Output the HTML only with 2 div's (column2 and column3) (using PHP).
2. Output the HTML including all div's and hidding the column1 via CSS (display:none).

What do you think is better?

The first option is some complicated, because I don't know what kind of dynamic content will be inside each column, and using PHP I will need to process the entire HTML to know if (column1, column2 or column3) are empty. I don't want to use Javascript, I only want to use one of the two options CSS or PHP.

OK now, maybe you are thinking that I can work with a default template for each page.

For example if (pageXYZ) doesn't have the column1 I will use a template like

```
...
<div class="column2">dynamic_content</div>
<div class="column3">dynamic_content</div>
...
```

but this is the worst, because in the future, if you need to modify the entire template you will need to modify each page. I don't know what to do.

Comment: You should use javascript. :) This is a client side problem with a client side solution!

Comment: Any particular reason not to use JS? It seems like the obvious answer right now.

Comment: I'd use the PHP if statement to set the class name based on the content and define the style as display:none; in the css. So the answer is both if you dont want to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the :empty CSS3 pseudo selector?  You could easily write:

```
div.column1:empty, div.column2:empty, div.column3:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

to accomplish the same thing without using PHP or Javascript.

Plus, it'll preserve the original template without having to resort to editing in the future, and allows the rule to be updated in one place outside of your template.